# Git push rejected to push to remote

Tags: git, git-push

I'm trying to push to my GitHub repository, [Link to my GitHub repo if needed](http://%5BText%5D(https://stackoverflow.com).)

```
To https://github.com/laukomatic/RL-k_armed_bandit.git                                                             
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
                                                                   error: failed to push some refs to https://github.com/laukomatic/RL-k_armed_bandit.git
                               hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
                                         hint: See the Note about fast-forwards in git push --help for details.
                                               From https://github.com/laukomatic/RL-k_armed_bandit
```

Than I tried pulling to update with:
`git pull origin main`.
But it didn't work it said:

```
 * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD                                              
                          Already up to date.
```

when I tried: `git status`, it gave:

```
On branch master                                                                           
 nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

But it is still not possible to push.

I have already did `git add .` and `git commit -m "some message"`.

Also if it helps, I'm a complete beginner, I watched one tech with Tim tutorial. Also when I firstly pushed to the remote repository I pushed with Plotting_results. Which was created as a checkout. Than I updated it with master checkout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different issues here. One is that you created the README directly at GitHub after having already pushed four commits on `main` to GitHub. So now GitHub has that commit (7d1e6cb9f61b0fd7e2b86207577705b1d0c22cc7) and you don't. So you cannot push until you have pulled that commit into your local.

The other issue is that you're working on `master` in your local but there is no `master` on GitHub. You said `git pull origin main`, and that causes `main` to get merged into your `master`. This is a messy mismatch and is confusing the heck out of you. If you want to be able to push from your local to `main`, you need to be on `main` and pull `main` from GitHub and then push to `main`. You should get rid of `master` locally so you don't get all confused about where you are and what you're doing.

Comment: Everything about your situation, almost, is discussed in my article https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/

Answer (score 0):

I tried `git push -u origin main`, but was getting **this error**,
[image]

then **I did fetch the origin main** and did the following things, look at the second image ***after the error***.

[image]